# Where to promote your indie game?

Tags: marketing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to advertise my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/where-to-advertise-my-game)

Let's say I have developed a game and I want to "get it out there".  What I have in mind is open-source, non-commercial games.

What websites do you know of where you can promote your newly developed game, rather than simply posting it on your blog?

Comment: I feel it is a duplicate, but you do specify open source so I will leave this open. However, List-type 'questions' should be CW as a minimum. Forced it.

Comment: Also note that 'open-source' and 'commercial' are not mutually exclusive (although, many would like you to believe that). I think there are a lot of people out there who'd be willing to pay a small fee for not having to worry about building the binary for their platform. I suppose there are also free games, which are not open-source.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://www.indiedb.com/ has just been created, and might be an excellent choice, in addition to David McGraw's recommendation.

http://www.igdb.com/indie Internet Game Database is a good place to add your indie game.

Answer (score 19):

How-to:

[www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4117/building_buzz_for_indie_games.php](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4117/building_buzz_for_indie_games.php)

How to deal with the press:

[gillen.cream.org/wordpress_html/?page_id=693](http://gillen.cream.org/wordpress_html/?page_id=693)

List of PC game reviewers:

[fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/links/fallout3-reviews.php](http://fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/links/fallout3-reviews.php)

Marketing Book:

[www.sellmorevideogames.com](http://www.sellmorevideogames.com)

Viral Marketing

[www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4210/building_the_foundation_of_a_.php](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/4210/building_the_foundation_of_a_.php)

Marketing for Indie Games

[www.slideshare.net/simoniker/igs-gdc-austin-john-graham-effective-marketing-for-indie-game-developers?src=related_normal&rel=2670032](http://www.slideshare.net/simoniker/igs-gdc-austin-john-graham-effective-marketing-for-indie-game-developers?src=related_normal&rel=2670032)

Indie Press Release service

[www.gamerelease.net](http://www.gamerelease.net)

Comment: The "List of PC game reviewers" example was awesome... Fallout 3, eh?

Comment: Has anyone sed gamerelease.net in a successfull way?

Answer (score 8):

I would create a post in several forums that I know of -

- gamedev.net
- devmaster.net
- tigsource.com
- igda.com

Essentially any game related forum. It's not easy 'getting it out there.' It's quite time consuming.

Aside from that, I would get active on http://www.moddb.com. There is a ton of activity and you can post your game, mod or add-on.

If you sign up on gamedev.net and pay a yearly fee one of the perks is listing your projects in their showcase - http://www.gamedev.net/community/gds/.

If you're working on something really really slick, you might want to think about writing in to some of these websites and see if they would write a post / review your game. That could help quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

**First, gamedev sites and forums:**

- [gamedev.net](http://gamedev.net)
- [devmaster.net](http://devmaster.net)
- [idga.org](http://idga.org)

> (warning: their site is REALLY slow, the forum may take 20 minutes to load... don't give up as it takes a long time).

**Then, indie communities:**

- [tigsource.com](http://tigsource.com)
- [www.indiedb.com](http://www.indiedb.com)
- [www.moddb.com](http://www.moddb.com) (well, sorta the same as indiedb, the forums are actually shared)

**Important blogs to send your PR stuff:**

- [rockpapershotgun.com](http://rockpapershotgun.com)
- [indiegames.com](http://indiegames.com)
- [pcgamer.com](http://pcgamer.com)

**Shareware distribution sites:**

- [tucows.com](http://tucows.com)
- [softpedia.com](http://softpedia.com)
- [download.com](http://download.com) (to upload to them, it is [upload.com](http://upload.com))

**Advertising services:**

- google ads
- [game-advertising-online.com](http://game-advertising-online.com)

**PR services:**

- [gamerelease.net](http://gamerelease.net)
- [gamespress.com](http://gamespress.com)

> I will add more stuff as I remember (most of those are post-its glued to my monitor)

Comment: This is a very nice article!

Answer (score 3):

Two more sites for promoting are http://www.gametunnel.com/ and http://www.gamerelease.net/

Comment: Except gametunnel is dead, since a year ago. (just check the last update)

Answer (score 3):

[Gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net) has a board on it's forum for game announcements (the Your Announcements board), which is pretty active.
There's also word of mouth - distributing it to friends, work colleagues, family. It doesn't HAVE to be on the web, though this isn't going to be as effective. On the other hand, it's a gurantee that someone will play it.

There's also forum signatures for most general use forums; especially gaming forums.

[Devmaster](http://www.devmaster.net) is also a popular site.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget those high traffic sites.

CNets Download.com, tucows.com, www.brothersoft.com, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget you can also write a press release, there are many sites out there that let you publish them for free, then many companies have the chance of seeing your press release.

Also send out free copies to review sites or lone reviews (individuals) If they like your game they may put it up and if you get lucky and get onto something like kotaku.com your sales could be greatly improved.

Regards

Mark

Comment: Can you post urls of such websites ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Visit www.altergamer.com - I'm the admin&manager there, use the contact form and give us some details - if we are interested, we will be happy to review your game. We are strong supporters of new and fairly ambitious projects.

Cheers,
Adam