# My game is mostly complete, how do I find a publisher?

Tags: android, ios, marketing, appstore

I've been working for quite a while on a game.

I'm mostly done with it.

Simply finishing the project, adding banners and just publishing it on google play / appstore probably won't bring in any money, at least without firstly investing some in promotion...

How do I go about finding companies that might be interested in either promoting or maybe even fully buying out such a product?

Comment: I'm sure you're not just trying to advertise and find a publisher here, so I edited your question to remove the stuff specific to *your* game. [How to promote a game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33134/how-to-get-a-game-popular-without-a-publisher?rq=1) is a question that's been asked. The answer to this question is likely, "ask around".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first step, is of course, **finishing your game**. The publisher rejection rate is high enough for even established professional game developers, *with complete projects*. [Sloperama Lesson 11, Section V](http://www.sloperama.com/advice/lesson11.htm)

You want to essentially do everything in your power to be as noticed as possible. Publishing is very risky, even when your game is complete, and you want to have everything done so that your potential publisher won't feel like their money isn't wasted.

Following that of course, you just need to prepare your pitch, and then get in touch.[Tom Sloper has an excellent article here about the game submission process.](http://sloperama.com/advice/lesson21.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Another option depending on the scope of your game is to skip the publishers and instead try to reach out to review sites and try to have an article written about your game. This is usually very hard for small phone games, but even if it won't work for this one its an important strategy to have knowledge of.