# How do I get more installs for my android app?

Tags: marketing, appstore

Me and my team developed a slot machine game, and posted it on Google Play. Right now, it sits in position 460+ of the casino category. The number of installs is less than 1,000 and daily users range between 90 and 140.

I want to increase the number of installs to promote my game in the store, but I need also these installs to be converted to daily users. I tried some big networks that provide a huge amount of installs, but they only convert to uninstalls.

Can anyone suggest a trusted source with good prices and good quality of installs?

Comment: what marketing have you done so far? or have you just focused on networking and 3rd part promoting?

Comment: Nothing yet, frankly. Have plans for organic search in app-store promotion first.

Comment: i would recommend other ways of promoting personally. Try things such as word to mouth, social media marketing, website promotion and such.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I need to start getting something out this game and ad-networks are not so much intersted in my amount of traffic - so I looked for short-time increase of users.

Comment: To put it bluntly, without spending money on other marketing areas and mass marketing the product your not going to get a quick increase. With the exception that your game catches on by itself (Although i assume this  isn't the case)

Comment: It seems you are attempting to simply purchase downloads. This is never going to convert to daily users. A user who is paid to download your app has no further motivation to actually *play* your game; in fact, in some cases these "installs" might actually come from hacked accounts. I would have to wonder if Google would deliberately permit this sort of thing; getting caught could likely result in not being allowed to publish to the Play Store at all.

Comment: Have you considered that your game might just not be very good? How much playtesting (with people not involved in the development) have you done?

Comment: Thanks for concern Philip, the game is good, I'm on my way to start promoting it on web and in facebook maybe - to achieve more users. And I also got some suggestions on ASO recently -  maybe I shall try to optimize to encrease the search position of my game, the competition in casino games is very high :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is advertisement to  a promoting service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

"Buying" installs isn't a sustainable marketing model. Such "bought" users are usually bots or employees of the company. These are fake users who won't actually use your app seriously.

It might help you to temporarily get a few ranks in the app store popularity charts, but unless you buy so many that you get into the toplist of a very frequent search term, that won't give you the exposure you need to attract real users. Also, Google, Apple et al. really hate people who use such underhanded tactics to fake the popularity of their products and will punish you accordingly when they catch you.

If you want to have a successful game, make a game which is worth being successful. Make something with a new, unique and innovative game idea which you can market properly using the methods described in the question ["How can I promote my game?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/how-can-i-promote-my-game).

Comment: Thanks Philip! This is a good explanation. I'll take it into cosideration. Still it's hard today to  enter a market an to compete with existing products. You start from the bottom and climb up very slowly, and the wish to get everything right now appears oftenly :) Thanks to you.