# My game is just about finished! What do I do now?

Tags: html5, html-canvas, marketing

I have an HTML5/canvas game just about finished and ready to launch. It's a 2d game in which you explore and disrupt a procedurally-generated landscape, crafting items and structures to survive. I have to finalize the 'ending' and fix a few bugs, but the game is pretty much ready for players.

The game will be free to play on the web, and I plan to begin working versions for iOS and the Mac App Store. I will also continue to add content to the game even after it launches.

Can anyone recommend things that I should remember to do before launching the game? Thanks!

Comment: Good luck with it! (post it here as a comment once it's online)

Comment: Here is the game for anyone who is interested: http://www.makenowonder.com/

Comment: Maybe it is not clear enough, but I can't seem to be able to get out of the shovel-mode?

Comment: If you are interested in selling your game, consider taking a look at [fgl.com](http://www.fgl.com). It's a website dedicated to the sale of casual games (inclusing flash, HTML5 and mobile). It also includes a forum where you might be able to get some nice feedback.

Comment: Just a quick bit of feedback (I know it's not the stackexchange thing to do, but i can't help myself): It's very hard to control the mouse when i can't see it directly (i don't know where my mouse is on a tile).

Answer (score 16):

Get a couple of friends and make them go through bugs and check all game assets. Think of ways of monetizing it, like implementing the Kongregate API or so.

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing some beta testing with friends already and it is definitely essential. Kongregate only accepts Flash and Unity games, mine is HTML5.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with Ef Es, get a couple of people, parents/friends whoever, and watch them play through it. It's the worse to launch a game only to find it really hard because you were use to the game mechanics.

I suggest maybe making a blog of the launch of your game, just go over the details, any updates can be listed there as well.

If money isn't a concern, try to get it on as many sites as possible. [The first answer to this post has a lot of sites](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/334/where-should-i-host-my-flash-games). Make sure to read all the reviews of what people liked and didn't like. Also let your all your friends that you know enjoy gaming know as well.

EDIT: Just realized not all of those sites accept HtML5 games, here are  two that accept Html5 games

- [HTML5 games](http://html5games.com/)
- [Google App Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore)

You can also use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and distribute it on iphone/android, which you said you are working on.